# What would be good gift card amount to give to a departing senior coworker?

Tags: colleagues

A very helpful coworker is leaving our company and our manager shared a link for us to leave a farewell message with the option to contribute to an Amazon gift card. I'm leaning towards contributing to the gift card -- as a junior engineer, I got a lot of support from her during the time we worked together.

However, I don't know what would be a good amount since I cannot see how much others have contributed, plus I've never given colleagues gift cards before. She also makes very good money if that matters. The default selections are $20, $30, $50. Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not only opinion based but also highly dependant on specific location and economy at the time

Comment: @solarflare Our team is 100% remote so I am not sure if location matters as much. The said departing colleague resides in NYC. But I see your point

Comment: Gift card is pretty impersonal...

Comment: The co-worker will not know what amount you gave.  So, it is entirely upto you.  OTOH, if you want to do something nice, send them an email thanking them for their help and cooperation

Comment: @keshlam - unless the colleague is an avid campaigner for employee rights or for multinationals to be taxed where they make their profits, in which case an Amazon gift card is offensively personal.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere: Gift cards are available from many/most stores, not just Amazon. I've given certs for my local used book stores, for restaurants, for home centers... Or you can give cash, but that shows even less attempt to express understanding of the individual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the gift card as you said is optional. You are not forced to contribute, nor should others contributing affect your choice (that's why you can't see how/who has contributed).

How much you give (if you decide to) is completely up to you and your current economical situation. If you want and can spare $50 go for it. Only can spare $20, go for it. Rather not, its ok as well.

My suggestion, leaving aside the gift card discussion, is that if you feel grateful and honored to have worked with this person is to go to them and thank them (not only via the link provided to leave a message).

You can do it face to face, or a call if you are remote/hybrid. I think that an honest thank you, and details on how they were kind and supportive and compliments on their professionalism and good luck on their future endeavors will be more meaningful than a $x gift card.